# why it prints only one "record/row"?

Tags: multi-index

I created a table with 5 rows/records.
I tried to print the whole table content with the following code:

```
require_auth(_self);
accounts_table accounts(_self, _self.value);
for(auto itr = accounts.begin(); itr != accounts.end();++itr) {
   print( itr->parent_account);
   print("\n");
}
```

But only got one row.

When I call the command `cleos -u  get table ACCOUNT SCOPE TABLENAME`, it shows all the 5 records.

Why does the code above only prints the first record?

Comment: I'm not sure why that code behaves that way, but can you try using C++11 syntax like `for(auto & itr : accounts )` and tell us how it works out?

Comment: thanks for your response, i just realize the scape caracter '\n' finalize the console output. for instance the code print("hi\n"); print ("how are you \n") only  dsiplay "hi" in the console

Comment: @kriskoin why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @kriskoin you may answer your question and accept it, so others can find it as well. Thank you.